# Can Connecting devices with the wrong type of cable (crossover/straight through) damage them?

Tags: crossover

This is a CCNA question, the title pretty much says it all. What would happen if I connected a device with the wrong type of cable? Could the cable damage the device in some way?

Comment: Are we talking about Ethernet, Arcnet, DECNet?  Give us more information so we can provide a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're talking about Ethernet connecting to Ethernet, without PoE (power over Ethernet) then no, connecting an Ethernet cable will not harm either device.

Connecting Ethernet to a modem port may harm one of the devices, but I forget which one.  Connecting Ethernet with PoE to a device with the incorrect cable MAY harm the device NOT supplying power. There are likely several other combinations which could cause harm to either or both sides.

Comment: Additionally, in the simple case of ethernet to a non-ancient switch, if you use a crossover cable it will auto-negotiate just fine.

Comment: So would you say its true in cases depending on the device the incorrect type is connected to?

Comment: Though I'm not completely sure what you're asking, I'll venture to say yes.  The compatibility or damage will depend on the two devices being connected together.  But in general Ethernet to Ethernet, straight through or cross-over, no harm will occur.